# masking the id of an employee in a select query

Tags: mysql

I have an ID which I want to mask the last 4 digits of that id.

example: my_id = 123456789

```
SELECT
concat(left(my_id,length(my_id) -4)) + ' ' + 'xxxx' AS masked_data
FROM
  dual ;
```

Expected output : 12345XXXX

But I am getting as 12345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings that you're concatenating should all be arguments to the `CONCAT()` function. `+` is for addition, not concatenation.

```
SELECT
concat(left(my_id, length(my_id) - 4), 'xxxx') AS masked_data
```

You also don't want a space before `xxxx`.

Comment: not likely to be an issue with this data, but mixing length() and left() can trip you up with non-ascii data; you almost always want char_length() instead